# Chess engine programmed in Python

Tags: python, performance, ai, chess

I programmed a chess AI in Python. It uses the alpha-beta algorithm with move ordering. I want it to be able to look further than depth 4, without increasing calculation time. I am wondering how I possibly could improve the efficiency of my code. I have a feeling that my code does a lot of unnecessary calculations.

```
king1_moved = False
king2_moved = False

rook1_left = False
rook1_right = False

rook2_left = False
rook2_right = False

iteration = 0

def game():
    board = create_starting_board()
    player1_pawn_promotion_line = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
    print_board(board)
    print("")
    print("")
    while True:
        castling = ""
        # castling:
        if board[110] == "r-1" and board[111] == " 0 " and board[112] == " 0 " and board[113] == " 0 " \
                and board[114] == "k-1":
            castling = input("Do you want to castle?")
            if castling == "y":
                x_piece = int(input("x_piece:"))
                y_piece = int(input("y_piece:"))
                x_move = int(input("x_move:"))
                y_move = int(input("y_move:"))

                piece_pos = (109 + x_piece) - (y_piece - 1) * 12
                move_pos = (109 + x_move) - (y_move - 1) * 12

                board[move_pos] = board[piece_pos]
                board[piece_pos] = " 0 "

                x_piece = int(input("x_piece:"))
                y_piece = int(input("y_piece:"))
                x_move = int(input("x_move:"))
                y_move = int(input("y_move:"))

                piece_pos = (109 + x_piece) - (y_piece - 1) * 12
                move_pos = (109 + x_move) - (y_move - 1) * 12

                board[move_pos] = board[piece_pos]
                board[piece_pos] = " 0 "
        if board[117] == "r-1" and board[116] == " 0 " and board[115] == " 0 " and board[114] == "k-1":
            castling = input("Do you want to castle?")
            if castling == "y":
                x_piece = int(input("x_piece:"))
                y_piece = int(input("y_piece:"))
                x_move = int(input("x_move:"))
                y_move = int(input("y_move:"))

                piece_pos = (109 + x_piece) - (y_piece - 1) * 12
                move_pos = (109 + x_move) - (y_move - 1) * 12

                board[move_pos] = board[piece_pos]
                board[piece_pos] = " 0 "

                x_piece = int(input("x_piece:"))
                y_piece = int(input("y_piece:"))
                x_move = int(input("x_move:"))
                y_move = int(input("y_move:"))

                piece_pos = (109 + x_piece) - (y_piece - 1) * 12
                move_pos = (109 + x_move) - (y_move - 1) * 12

                board[move_pos] = board[piece_pos]
                board[piece_pos] = " 0 "
        if castling != "y":
            x_piece = int(input("x_piece:"))
            y_piece = int(input("y_piece:"))
            x_move = int(input("x_move:"))
            y_move = int(input("y_move:"))

            piece_pos = (109 + x_piece) - (y_piece - 1) * 12
            move_pos = (109 + x_move) - (y_move - 1) * 12

            board[move_pos] = board[piece_pos]
            board[piece_pos] = " 0 "

            if "p-1" in board:
                if board.index("p-1") in player1_pawn_promotion_line:
                    board[move_pos] = "q-1"

        # check if king/queen has moved:
        global king1_moved, rook1_right, rook1_left
        if board[move_pos] == "k-1":
            king1_moved = False
        elif board[move_pos] == "r-1" and piece_pos == 110:
            rook1_left = False
        elif board[move_pos] == "r-1" and piece_pos == 117:
            rook1_right = False

        print_board(board)
        print("")
        print("")

        maximize(board, -1, 4, -100000, 100000)


def sort_moves(scores, piece_positions, possible_moves,  player):

    where_did_items_go = []

    if player == 1:
        sorted_scores = sorted(scores, reverse=True)
    else:
        sorted_scores = sorted(scores, reverse=False)

    for item in scores:
        num = sorted_scores.index(item)
        while num in where_did_items_go:
            num += 1
        where_did_items_go.append(num)

    piece = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(where_did_items_go, piece_positions))]
    possible = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(where_did_items_go, possible_moves))]

    return piece, possible


def maximize(board, player, depth, alpha, beta):
    max_depth = 4
    player2_pawn_promotion_line = [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]
    pos = -1
    if depth == 0:
        return evaluation(board)
    max_value = alpha
    positions, moves = find_all_possible_moves(board, player)
    for move in moves:
        pawn_promotion = False
        global iteration
        iteration += 1
        pos += 1
        # perform move
        if isinstance(move, int):
            piece = board[move]
            board[move] = board[positions[pos]]
            board[positions[pos]] = " 0 "
            # pawn promotion
            if "p-2" in board:
                if player == -1 and board.index("p-2") in player2_pawn_promotion_line:
                    board[move] = "q-2"
                    pawn_promotion = True
            value = minimize(board, player * -1, depth - 1, max_value, beta)
            # reverse move
            if not pawn_promotion:
                board[positions[pos]] = board[move]
                board[move] = piece
            else:
                board[positions[pos]] = "p-2"
                board[move] = piece
        else:
            piece_1 = board[move[0]]
            piece_2 = board[move[1]]
            board[move[0]] = board[positions[pos][0]]
            board[move[1]] = board[positions[pos][1]]
            board[positions[pos][0]] = " 0 "
            board[positions[pos][1]] = " 0 "
            value = minimize(board, player * -1, depth - 1, max_value, beta)
            # reverse move
            board[positions[pos][0]] = board[move[0]]
            board[positions[pos][1]] = board[move[1]]
            board[move[0]] = piece_1
            board[move[1]] = piece_2
        if value >= max_value:
            max_value = value
            best_move = move
            best_piece = positions[pos]
            if max_value >= beta:
                break
    if depth == max_depth:
        # perform move + check if kings/rooks moved
        if moves == []:
            print("Check_Mate: You won!")
            exit()
        if isinstance(best_move, int):
            board[best_move] = board[best_piece]
            board[best_piece] = " 0 "
            # pawn promotion
            if "p-2" in board:
                if board.index("p-2") in player2_pawn_promotion_line:
                    board[best_move] = "q-2"
            # check if king/queen has moved:
            global king2_moved, rook2_right, rook2_left
            if board[best_move] == "k-2":
                king2_moved = True
            elif board[best_move] == "r-2" and best_piece == 26:
                rook2_left = True
            elif board[best_move] == "r-2" and best_piece == 33:
                rook2_right = True
        else:
            board[best_move[0]] = board[best_piece[0]]
            board[best_move[1]] = board[best_piece[1]]
            board[best_piece[0]] = " 0 "
            board[best_piece[1]] = " 0 "
        print_board(board)
        print(max_value)
        print(iteration)
        print("")
        print("")
    return max_value


def minimize(board, player, depth, alpha, beta):
    player1_pawn_promotion_line = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
    pos = -1
    if depth == 0:
        return evaluation(board)
    min_value = beta
    positions, moves = find_all_possible_moves(board, player)
    for move in moves:
        global iteration
        iteration += 1
        pawn_promotion = False
        pos += 1
        # perform move
        if isinstance(move, int):
            piece = board[move]
            board[move] = board[positions[pos]]
            board[positions[pos]] = " 0 "
            # pawn promotion
            if "p-1" in board:
                if player == 1 and board.index("p-1") in player1_pawn_promotion_line:
                    board[move] = "q-1"
                    pawn_promotion = True
            value = maximize(board, player * -1, depth - 1, alpha, min_value)
            # reverse move
            if not pawn_promotion:
                board[positions[pos]] = board[move]
                board[move] = piece
            else:
                board[positions[pos]] = "p-1"
                board[move] = piece
        else:
            piece_1 = board[move[0]]
            piece_2 = board[move[1]]
            board[move[0]] = board[positions[pos][0]]
            board[move[1]] = board[positions[pos][1]]
            board[positions[pos][0]] = " 0 "
            board[positions[pos][1]] = " 0 "
            value = maximize(board, player * -1, depth - 1, alpha, min_value)
            # reverse move
            board[positions[pos][0]] = board[move[0]]
            board[positions[pos][1]] = board[move[1]]
            board[move[0]] = piece_1
            board[move[1]] = piece_2
        if value < min_value:
            min_value = value
            if min_value <= alpha:
                break
    return min_value


def evaluation(board):
    # simple material_count
    king = 3600
    queen = 360
    rook = 200
    bishop = 120
    knight = 120
    pawn = 40

    value = 0

    search_range = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
                    38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,
                    50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57,
                    62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
                    74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81,
                    86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93,
                    98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105,
                    110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]

    prawn_table_AI = [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0,
                        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0,
                        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 10, 10,  5,-10,-10, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 5,  0,  5,  0,  0, 5,  0,  5, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0,  0,  5, 20, 20, 5,  0,  0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  5,  5, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 5,  5,  5, 10, 10, 5,  5,  5, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0,
                        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    knight_table_AI = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 15, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 15, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    bishop_table_AI = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0,0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0,0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0,0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0,0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0,0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0,0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    rook_table_AI = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    prawn_table_H = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 20, 20, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 10, 10, 5, -10, -10, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0,
                     0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    knight_table_H = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 15, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 15, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]

    bishop_table_H = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    rook_table_H = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    # material_score
    for square in search_range:
        if "1" in board[square]:
            player_string = "1"
            player_int = -1
        else:
            player_string = "2"
            player_int = 1

        if "p-" + player_string in board[square]:
            value = value + player_int * pawn
        if "n-" + player_string in board[square]:
            value = value + player_int * knight
        if "b-" + player_string in board[square]:
            value = value + player_int * bishop
        if "r-" + player_string in board[square]:
            value = value + player_int * rook
        if "q-" + player_string in board[square]:
            value = value + player_int * queen
        if "k-" + player_string in board[square]:
            value = value + player_int * king

    # position score
    for square in search_range:
        if "1" in board[square]:
            if "p" in board[square]:
                value -= prawn_table_H[square]
            if "b" in board[square]:
                value -= bishop_table_H[square]
            if "n" in board[square]:
                value -= knight_table_H[square]
            if "r" in board[square]:
                value -= rook_table_H[square]
        else:
            if "p" in board[square]:
                value += prawn_table_AI[square]
            if "b" in board[square]:
                value += bishop_table_AI[square]
            if "n" in board[square]:
                value += knight_table_AI[square]
            if "r" in board[square]:
                value += rook_table_AI[square]








    # Castling
    if board[31] == "r-2" and board[32] == "k-2":
        value += 4
    if board[29] == "r-2" and board[28] == "k-2":
        value += 4
    if board[115] == "r-1" and board[116] == "k-1":
        value -= 4
    if board[113] == "r-1" and board[112] == "k-1":
        value -= 4

    return value


def create_starting_board():
    board = ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", "r-2", "n-2", "b-2", "q-2", "k-2", "b-2", "n-2", "r-2", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", "p-2", "p-2", "p-2", "p-2", "p-2", "p-2", "p-2", "p-2", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", "p-1", "p-1", "p-1", "p-1", "p-1", "p-1", "p-1", "p-1", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", "r-1", "n-1", "b-1", "q-1", "k-1", "b-1", "n-1", "r-1", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x",
             "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
    return board


def print_board(board):
    for i in range(8):
        if i > 0:
            print("---------------------------------")
        print("¦" + board[26 + i * 12] + "¦" + board[12 * i + 27] + "¦" + board[12 * i + 28] + "¦" + board[
            i * 12 + 29] + "¦" + board[12 * i + 30] + "¦" + board[12 * i + 31] + "¦" + board[12 * i + 32] + "¦"
              + board[12 * i + 33] + "¦")


def king_exists(board, player):
    search_range = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
                    38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,
                    50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57,
                    62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
                    74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81,
                    86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93,
                    98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105,
                    110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]
    if player == 1:
        player_string = "1"
    else:
        player_string = "2"
    for i in search_range:
        if "k-" + player_string in board[i]:
            return True
    return False


def king_under_attack(board, player):
    position, moves = make_all_next_moves(board, player * -1)
    pos = -1
    player1_pawn_promotion_line = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
    player2_pawn_promotion_line = [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]
    # perform all moves and check if in one of the moves the king doesn't exist, if true, then the king is under check
    # in the current board_state
    for move in moves:
        pawn_promotion = False
        pos += 1
        if isinstance(move, int):
            piece = board[move]
            board[move] = board[position[pos]]
            board[position[pos]] = " 0 "
            # pawn promotion
            if "p-1" in board:
                if player == 1 and board.index("p-1") in player1_pawn_promotion_line:
                    board[move] = "q-1"
                    pawn_promotion = True
            if "p-2" in board:
                if player == -1 and board.index("p-2") in player2_pawn_promotion_line:
                    board[move] = "q-2"
                    pawn_promotion = True
            if not king_exists(board, player):
                # reverse move
                if not pawn_promotion:
                    board[position[pos]] = board[move]
                    board[move] = piece
                else:
                    if player == 1:
                        board[position[pos]] = "p-1"
                        board[move] = piece
                    else:
                        board[position[pos]] = "p-2"
                        board[move] = piece
                return True
            # reverse move
            if not pawn_promotion:
                board[position[pos]] = board[move]
                board[move] = piece
            else:
                if player == 1:
                    board[position[pos]] = "p-1"
                    board[move] = piece
                else:
                    board[position[pos]] = "p-2"
                    board[move] = piece

        else:
            piece_1 = board[move[0]]
            piece_2 = board[move[1]]
            board[move[0]] = board[position[pos][0]]
            board[move[1]] = board[position[pos][1]]
            board[position[pos][0]] = " 0 "
            board[position[pos][1]] = " 0 "
            if not king_exists(board, player):
                # reverse move
                board[position[pos][0]] = board[move[0]]
                board[position[pos][1]] = board[move[1]]
                board[move[0]] = piece_1
                board[move[1]] = piece_2
                return True
            # reverse move
            board[position[pos][0]] = board[move[0]]
            board[position[pos][1]] = board[move[1]]
            board[move[0]] = piece_1
            board[move[1]] = piece_2
    return False


def make_all_next_moves(board, player):
    possible_moves = []
    piece_position = []
    search_range = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
                    38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,
                    50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57,
                    62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
                    74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81,
                    86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93,
                    98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105,
                    110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]
    pawn1_start = [98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105]
    pawn2_start = [38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]

    if player == 1:
        player_string = "1"
        attack_player = "2"
        pawn_starting_positions = pawn1_start
    else:
        player_string = "2"
        attack_player = "1"
        pawn_starting_positions = pawn2_start
    # find all possible moves with pawn, bishop, knight, rook, queen and king
    for i in search_range:
        # pawn
        if "p-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # pawn_forward
            if board[i - player * 12] == " 0 ":
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - player * 12)
            # pawn_right
            if attack_player in board[i - player * 11]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - player * 11)
            # pawn_left
            if attack_player in board[i - player * 13]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - player * 13)
            # pawn_two_forward
            if board[i - player * 24] == " 0 " and board[i - player * 12] == " 0 " and i in pawn_starting_positions:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - player * 24)

        # bishop
        if "b-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # bishop_up_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 11
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # bishop_up_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 13
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # bishop_down_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 11
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # bishop_down_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 13
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
        # knight
        if "n-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # 8 cases
            if " 0 " in board[i - 23] or attack_player in board[i - 23]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 23)
            if " 0 " in board[i - 25] or attack_player in board[i - 25]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 25)
            if " 0 " in board[i - 10] or attack_player in board[i - 10]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 10)
            if " 0 " in board[i - 14] or attack_player in board[i - 14]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 14)
            if " 0 " in board[i + 23] or attack_player in board[i + 23]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 23)
            if " 0 " in board[i + 25] or attack_player in board[i + 25]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 25)
            if " 0 " in board[i + 10] or attack_player in board[i + 10]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 10)
            if " 0 " in board[i + 14] or attack_player in board[i + 14]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 14)
        # rook
        if "r-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # rook_up
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 12
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # rook_down
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 12
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # rook_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 1
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # rook_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 1
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
        # queen
        if "q-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # queen_up
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 12
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_down
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 12
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 1
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 1
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_up_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 11
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_up_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 13
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_down_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 11
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_down_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 13
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
        # king
        if "k-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # king_up
            if " 0 " in board[i - 12] or attack_player in board[i - 12]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 12)
            # king_down
            if " 0 " in board[i + 12] or attack_player in board[i + 12]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 12)
            # king_right
            if " 0 " in board[i + 1] or attack_player in board[i + 1]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 1)
            # king_left
            if " 0 " in board[i - 1] or attack_player in board[i - 1]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 1)
            # king_up_right
            if " 0 " in board[i - 11] or attack_player in board[i - 11]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 11)
            # king_up_left
            if " 0 " in board[i - 13] or attack_player in board[i - 13]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 13)
            # king_down_right
            if " 0 " in board[i + 11] or attack_player in board[i + 11]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 11)
            # king_down_left
            if " 0 " in board[i + 13] or attack_player in board[i + 13]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 13)
    # Castling
    global king1_moved, king2_moved, rook1_left, rook1_right, rook2_left, rook2_right
    if player == 1 and not king1_moved:
        # 2 castling options
        if board[110] == "r-1" and board[111] == " 0 " and board[112] == " 0 " \
                and board[113] == " 0 " and board[114] == "k-1" and not rook1_left:
            piece_position.append([114, 110])
            possible_moves.append([112, 113])
        if board[117] == "r-1" and board[116] == " 0 " and board[115] == " 0 " \
                and board[114] == "k-1" and not rook1_right:
            piece_position.append([114, 117])
            possible_moves.append([116, 115])
    if player == -1 and not king2_moved:
        # 2 castling options
        if board[26] == "r-2" and board[27] == " 0 " and board[28] == " 0 " \
                and board[29] == " 0 " and board[30] == "k-2" and not rook2_left:
            piece_position.append([30, 26])
            possible_moves.append([28, 29])
        if board[33] == "r-2" and board[32] == " 0 " and board[31] == " 0 " \
                and board[30] == "k-2" and not rook2_right:
            piece_position.append([30, 33])
            possible_moves.append([32, 31])

    # En passe --> maybe add it later on (a bit unnessecary but okay i guess i'll just add it later)

    return piece_position, possible_moves


def find_all_possible_moves(board, player):
    possible_moves = []
    piece_position = []
    search_range = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
                    38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,
                    50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57,
                    62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
                    74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81,
                    86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93,
                    98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105,
                    110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]
    pawn1_start = [98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105]
    pawn2_start = [38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]

    if player == 1:
        player_string = "1"
        attack_player = "2"
        pawn_starting_positions = pawn1_start
    else:
        player_string = "2"
        attack_player = "1"
        pawn_starting_positions = pawn2_start
    # find all possible moves with pawn, bishop, knight, rook, queen and king
    for i in search_range:
        # pawn
        if "p-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # pawn_forward
            if board[i - player * 12] == " 0 ":
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - player * 12)
            # pawn_right
            if attack_player in board[i - player * 11]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - player * 11)
            # pawn_left
            if attack_player in board[i - player * 13]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - player * 13)
            # pawn_two_forward
            if board[i - player * 24] == " 0 " and board[i - player * 12] == " 0 " and i in pawn_starting_positions:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - player * 24)
        # bishop
        if "b-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # bishop_up_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 11
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # bishop_up_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 13
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # bishop_down_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 11
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # bishop_down_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 13
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
        # knight
        if "n-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # 8 cases
            if " 0 " in board[i - 23] or attack_player in board[i - 23]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 23)
            if " 0 " in board[i - 25] or attack_player in board[i - 25]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 25)
            if " 0 " in board[i - 10] or attack_player in board[i - 10]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 10)
            if " 0 " in board[i - 14] or attack_player in board[i - 14]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 14)
            if " 0 " in board[i + 23] or attack_player in board[i + 23]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 23)
            if " 0 " in board[i + 25] or attack_player in board[i + 25]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 25)
            if " 0 " in board[i + 10] or attack_player in board[i + 10]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 10)
            if " 0 " in board[i + 14] or attack_player in board[i + 14]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 14)
        # rook
        if "r-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # rook_up
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 12
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # rook_down
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 12
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # rook_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 1
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # rook_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 1
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
        # queen
        if "q-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # queen_up
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 12
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_down
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 12
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 1
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 1
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_up_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 11
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_up_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x - 13
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_down_left
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 11
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            # queen_down_right
            x = i
            while True:
                x = x + 13
                if board[x] == " 0 ":
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                elif attack_player in board[x]:
                    piece_position.append(i)
                    possible_moves.append(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
        # king
        if "k-" + player_string in board[i]:
            # king_up
            if " 0 " in board[i - 12] or attack_player in board[i - 12]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 12)
            # king_down
            if " 0 " in board[i + 12] or attack_player in board[i + 12]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 12)
            # king_right
            if " 0 " in board[i + 1] or attack_player in board[i + 1]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 1)
            # king_left
            if " 0 " in board[i - 1] or attack_player in board[i - 1]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 1)
            # king_up_right
            if " 0 " in board[i - 11] or attack_player in board[i - 11]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 11)
            # king_up_left
            if " 0 " in board[i - 13] or attack_player in board[i - 13]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i - 13)
            # king_down_right
            if " 0 " in board[i + 11] or attack_player in board[i + 11]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 11)
            # king_down_left
            if " 0 " in board[i + 13] or attack_player in board[i + 13]:
                piece_position.append(i)
                possible_moves.append(i + 13)

    # Castling
    global king1_moved, king2_moved, rook1_left, rook1_right, rook2_left, rook2_right
    if not king_under_attack(board, player):
        if player == 1 and not king1_moved:
            # 2 castling options
            if board[110] == "r-1" and board[111] == " 0 " and board[112] == " 0 " \
                    and board[113] == " 0 " and board[114] == "k-1" and not rook1_left:
                piece_position.append([114, 110])
                possible_moves.append([112, 113])
            if board[117] == "r-1" and board[116] == " 0 " and board[115] == " 0 " \
                    and board[114] == "k-1" and not rook1_right:
                piece_position.append([114, 117])
                possible_moves.append([116, 115])
        if player == -1 and not king2_moved:
            # 2 castling options
            if board[26] == "r-2" and board[27] == " 0 " and board[28] == " 0 " \
                    and board[29] == " 0 " and board[30] == "k-2" and not rook2_left:
                piece_position.append([30, 26])
                possible_moves.append([28, 29])
            if board[33] == "r-2" and board[32] == " 0 " and board[31] == " 0 " \
                    and board[30] == "k-2" and not rook2_right:
                piece_position.append([30, 33])
                possible_moves.append([32, 31])

    scores = []
    player1_pawn_promotion_line = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
    player2_pawn_promotion_line = [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]
    for i in range(len(possible_moves) - 1, -1, -1):
        pawn_promotion = False
        deletion = False
        if isinstance(possible_moves[i], int):
            piece = board[possible_moves[i]]
            board[possible_moves[i]] = board[piece_position[i]]
            board[piece_position[i]] = " 0 "
            # pawn promotion
            if "p-1" in board:
                if player == 1 and board.index("p-1") in player1_pawn_promotion_line:
                    board[possible_moves[i]] = "q-1"
                    pawn_promotion = True
            if "p-2" in board:
                if player == -1 and board.index("p-2") in player2_pawn_promotion_line:
                    board[possible_moves[i]] = "q-2"
                    pawn_promotion = True
            if king_under_attack(board, player):
                deletion = True
            else:
                # add score for move ordering
                scores.append(evaluation(board))
            # reverse move
            if not pawn_promotion:
                board[piece_position[i]] = board[possible_moves[i]]
                board[possible_moves[i]] = piece
            else:
                if player == 1:
                    board[piece_position[i]] = "p-1"
                    board[possible_moves[i]] = piece
                else:
                    board[piece_position[i]] = "p-2"
                    board[possible_moves[i]] = piece
        else:
            piece_1 = board[possible_moves[i][0]]
            piece_2 = board[possible_moves[i][1]]
            board[possible_moves[i][0]] = board[piece_position[i][0]]
            board[possible_moves[i][1]] = board[piece_position[i][1]]
            board[piece_position[i][0]] = " 0 "
            board[piece_position[i][1]] = " 0 "
            if king_under_attack(board, player):
                deletion = True
            else:
                # add score for move ordering
                scores.append(evaluation(board))
            # reverse move
            board[piece_position[i][0]] = board[possible_moves[i][0]]
            board[piece_position[i][1]] = board[possible_moves[i][1]]
            board[possible_moves[i][0]] = piece_1
            board[possible_moves[i][1]] = piece_2
        if deletion:
            del possible_moves[i]
            del piece_position[i]

    # En passe --> maybe add it later on (a bit unnecessary but okay i guess i'll just add it later)

    piece_position, possible_moves = sort_moves(scores, piece_position,possible_moves, player)

    return piece_position, possible_moves

game()
```

Here is a description of how my program works:

This is one of my first attempts on making a chess-AI. It uses alpha-beta pruning with move ordering. 
The program isn't finished, but it is already usable. 
It knows about pawn promotion and castling, but I haven't yet implemented En passet. 
It currently searches at a depth of 4.

How to use it:
When you start it up, the board will be printed out and the human starts playing with the white pieces. 
The human player has to enter the coordinates of the piece to move and after that, the coordinates where he wants to move the selected piece too 
(Unlike in the AI-functions I have currently not implemented a function, which would only allow legal moves by the human.) After that, the updated board is printed.

```
¦r-2¦n-2¦b-2¦q-2¦k-2¦b-2¦n-2¦r-2¦
---------------------------------
¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦
---------------------------------
¦r-1¦n-1¦b-1¦q-1¦k-1¦b-1¦n-1¦r-1¦

x_piece:4
y_piece:2
x_move:4
y_move:4

¦r-2¦n-2¦b-2¦q-2¦k-2¦b-2¦n-2¦r-2¦
---------------------------------
¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦p-1¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦ 0 ¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦
---------------------------------
¦r-1¦n-1¦b-1¦q-1¦k-1¦b-1¦n-1¦r-1¦
```

Then, it's the AI's turn. It tries to find the best move with alpha-beta pruning (with move ordering). The evaluation function takes into consideration: 
the position of the pieces (with the help of hash tables) and material balance. When it finishes calculating, it performs the move and prints the updated board. 
Under the board, it spits out its predicted score and under that the number of chess boards it searched through:

```
¦r-2¦n-2¦b-2¦q-2¦k-2¦b-2¦n-2¦r-2¦
---------------------------------
¦p-2¦p-2¦ 0 ¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦p-2¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦p-2¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦p-1¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦ 0 ¦
---------------------------------
¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦ 0 ¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦p-1¦
---------------------------------
¦r-1¦n-1¦b-1¦q-1¦k-1¦b-1¦n-1¦r-1¦

25                                              <--- score prediction

141936                                          <--- amount of searched chess 
                                                     boards
```

The goal with this project is to make an AI which outperforms decent chess players. 
I would like it to reach an ELO somewhere around 1600, but in order to do that, my number 1 priority is to improve the search depth. 
The problem with this is that it already takes an age to search at depth 4. I wonder if anyone could help me and point at some improvements I could make. 
My programming skills are quite basic and I probably should comment my code better.

Comment: Traditionally White and Black pieces are represented with upper- and lowercase letters respectively. `-1` and `-2` look noisy.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, I'll probably be changing this sometime in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions are really long. For example `game()` has 88 lines.

Some parts are extracted (great!), for example `print_board()`. I would do the same for example with castling code that is really long and move it to its own function.

Shorter function make analysis of code easier - it is much easier to notice mistakes.

> how I possibly could improve the efficiency of my code. I have a feeling that my code does a lot of unnecessary calculations.

I would recommend using one of profilers (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script ) - special tools that report which functions are the most costly. It allows to spot functions where optimization will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll be making my functions as short as possible and then test it in the profilers you sent me. I am going to post the updated code later on.

Comment: Note that you should not update code in this question but rather post a new question (and possibly select one of the answers here as accepted).